# Automatic Email Notification

Tags: mysql, sql-server, jsp, servlets

[image]

In this project: when a user enter a date. Then all due books will show
   in show Due Details table and when user click the Email Alert(hyper-link). Automatic
   will go to that particular student: "You have crossed your due date".Inside this
   `Studentid`, `studentName`, `BookName`, `BookNo`, `Author`, `Eddition`, `Subject`, `Return Date` along with `fine`.please let me know if you know this automatic mail Notification coding

Comment: Get the email of the student from the database, along with the rest of the needed data, and use [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) to send an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clicks on the `Email Alert` hyper link, invoke a servlet which gets the email address of the student calculate the fine and use [Java Mail](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2001/jw-1026-javamail.html) to send automated email.

Hope it helps.